# How to call json rest service in html through dojo

Tags: javascript, json, rest, maven, dojo

I am developing an maven web application using rest web services. I am trying to call the simple web service from the dojo. But I  did not know getting started to call rest service through dojo. My web service code is:

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces("application/json")
public ArrayList dynamicFetch() {

    ArrayList<User> ar = new ArrayList<User>();
    User u1 = new User(1,"Test",30);
    ar.add(u1);
    u1 = new User(2,"test2",31);
    ar.add(u1);
    return ar;
}
```

Which executes and shows

```
[{"age":30,"name":"Test","id":1},{"age":31,"name":"test2","id":2}]
```

How can i call this json object in html through dojo since all my elements are dojo..?

Please Help any help will be apprciated more

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at dojo.xhrGet ::http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget

Answer (score 0):

Prior to dojo v1.7, try this:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
  url: "/users",
  handleAs:"json",
  load: function (data) {
    // data is the array object it responds.
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

See the [Dojo Ajax reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/ajax.html) for details.